# SQLException in JavaFX Constructor

Tags: java, javafx, constructor, sqlexception

I have created a scene that shows data which gets fetched from Database. This data is assigned to variables in the Constructor called 'Details()'. 
Constructor takes an argument 'rollNo'. I am supposed to assign the data to variables in the constructor from Database querying on the basis of 'rollNo' .

I don't understand why this is giving **SQLException** .....

Please help

```
public class Details extends Application {

static Connection con = ConnectionUtil.getDataBaseConnection();
String query = "SELECT * from student WHERE rno = ?";

ResultSet rs;

PreparedStatement pst;

public static String name;
public static String course;
public static String roll;
public static String address;
public static String phone;
public static String yoj;
public static String parent;
public static String parPhone;
public static String attendance;


    Details(String rollNo) {
     System.out.println("Details rollNo = " + rollNo);
     try {
            roll = rollNo;

            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, rollNo);

            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            name = rs.getString("name");
            course = rs.getString("course");
            roll = rs.getString("rno");
            address = rs.getString("address");
            phone = rs.getString("contact");
            yoj = rs.getString("yoj");
            parent = rs.getString("prntName");
            parPhone = rs.getString("prntCntct");
            attendance = rs.getString("classesAttended");
            System.out.println("***" + rs.getString("name") + "***");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {



        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXML/Details.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,750,420);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Attendance AITH");
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

**It gives following output on console:**

```
    Details rollNo = 3
    java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:516)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:944)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:966)
        at application.Details.<init>(Details.java:45)
        at application.StudentTableUtil$3$1.lambda$0(StudentTableUtil.java:150)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    controller Details.name=null
    ****************************3***********
```

Comment: Well, in his exception he writes what was wrong. We know where to know after keeping it in secret :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't got you... Can you clarify please...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the full error message of the exception. ([edit] your question do **not** post additional information in comments)

Comment: Edited (Added the Output on console)

Comment: use `if(rs.next()) { ...` before call rs.getXXX

Answer (score 1):

If you don't understand why an exception is raised, then look at what the system is telling you about it (hint : e. getMessage() ).

That said, looking at your code, you are accessing the data without first checking that there is any data in the first place, so that might be the reason.

Comment: But it is giving SQLException

Comment: Yes you are right it wasn't working because I was fetching the data without checking.